# Prove that a set with n elements in union with an element not in the set has n+1 elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose $A$ has $n$ elements and suppose $a \notin A$, prove that $A \cup \{a\}$ has $n+1$ elements.

I am pretty sure that I am supposed to use something with one to one and onto functions.  It all seems difficult sinse the result is so intuitively obvious.  I have started working on it but I really don't feel like it is correct.

Suppose $f$ is a one to one and onto function $f: A \to A\cup \{a\}$. Since $f$ is an onto function, $Range(f)=A\cup \{a\}$.  Since $a \notin A$, and $A$ has n elements, then $A \cup \{a\}$ has  $n+1$ elements.

Comment: Do you know what it means for a set to have $n$ elements?

Comment: Umm, I don't think I do when you ask it like that.  I'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: By definition, a set $A$ has $n$ elements if, and only if, there exists a bijection between $\{k\in \mathbb N\colon 0\leq k<n\}$ and $A$, (assuming $0\in \mathbb N$).The first set if often denoted by $[n]$.

Comment: @GitGud: In my experience $[n]$ more often denotes $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ — almost always, in combinatorics. And in an elementary course having cardinality $n$ may be defined in terms of this set rather than the ordinal $n$.